# Tableau - Return a dimension with the MAX value

Tags: if-statement, max, case, visualization, tableau-api

I am pretty new with Tableau and I need your help for a visualization.

I have Col.1 = Country; Col.2 = Product name; Col. 3 = #Sales

**I want to make a table that displays for each Country the Product name that has the maximum amount of sales.**

E.g.

Country | Product
AT      | Shoes

where shoes is the product with the max sales.

I had thought of a calculated field like this: **if sum[Sales] = max([Sales]) then [Product Name] else Null END** but it gives me an error.

Any idea of how to solve it?

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: Looking at your example you shouldn't need a calculated field - can;t you simply filter your product dimension for the 'top 1' from SUM of sales, below country?

Comment: That did not work. However, the solution proposed by Jil worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending your method , you need a **FIXED LOD** to find the MAX(Sales) within **Col1** and then output the level within **Col2** matching with this MAX(Sales).

```
IF ([Sales])== ({FIXED [Cat1]:MAX([Sales])}) THEN [Cat2] ELSE NULL END
```

Then add the Calculated Field to the **Filter** and filter out the **NULL's**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually worked and it was exactly what I was looking for!